# React-Redux connect

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have two queries regarding react-redux connect

the connect can be called with two arguments
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps

1. Please Correct me if I am wrong, `<Provider store={store}>  </Provider>` 
   In mapStateToProps (first argument in connect())
   mapStateToProps = (**state**) => ({....}) 

   **state** over here is the same as store.getState(); ??

   please provider a bit more explaination to this
2. Please explain the usage of mapDispatchToProps with a beginner's example.

Comment: The [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) explain this with an easy to understand example.

Comment: yes the `state` argument is essentially the result of `store.getState()`.  Your function gets called each time the store is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapDispatchToProps` is a function that gets `dispatch` function as argument. You're expected to return an object, where you `map` keys with a function to dispatch an action.

Example time:

```
connect(/* ...*/, function(dispatch) {
    return {
        sayHello: function() { dispatch("ACTION_TYPE_HELLO")}
    }
   }
```

Connected components will receive prop `sayHello`, which is a function, where `this.props.sayHello()` will dispatch an action `ACTION_TYPE_HELLO` to the store.